# Struggling using zIndex to order views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to load a component on top of another. In my demo I have two screens that are conditionally rendered using a slider button(I would use a simple text button but I want to make sure the animation works). Screen 1 is just a grey screen and screen 2 is a screen of react native maps being rendered.

I would like the slider button to be on top of the map. I need the map to be full page. Originally I tried using zIndex but that is not working.

I have a working demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/zindez)

App.js

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      visible: true,
      whichComponentToShow: 'Screen1'
    };
}

goToMap = () => {
  this.setState({whichComponentToShow: 'Screen2'})
}
goToList = () => {
  this.setState({whichComponentToShow: 'Screen1'})
}

  render(){

    const SliderRender = (
      <Slider
        renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
          key="slider"
          style={{zIndex: 10}}
         />
      );
    
     if(this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1'){
      return(
       <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>  
        
        {SliderRender}

          <ListHome
            renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
            renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    else if(this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2'){
      return(
       <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>

        <MapHome
          renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
          
        />

        {SliderRender}
 
       </View>
      );
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `View` with `position: absolute` to wrap the slider buttons.

```
render() {
  const { whichComponentToShow } = this.state;

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1' && <ListHome />}
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2' && <MapHome />}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0}}>
        <Slider
          renderMap={this.goToMap}
          renderList={this.goToList}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would still like the map to be the entire page though.

Comment: Understood. I've updated the answer.

Comment: So visually that looks perfect. Only thing I noticed is the animation seems to stop working. You can render it before the Maphome to see the animation working how it should be. Any idea as to why adding a view to the sliderRender would cause the animation to stop working/re render?

Comment: That's because the slider component was being rerendered between screens. So the `active` state would always be `false`. The reason it worked in the initial code is that React understood those are the same components and reused the slider without unmounting it. I've updated the code again to fix this issue.